# Saving web page (ctrl+s) in opera not working correctly in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, opera

When I save a web page on opera browser, file explorer opens up but `save` and `cancel` button are not working correctly. While on other browsers, everything is working fine.

I need to quit the whole browser to return to normal conditions.